# SendPingAsync TimedOut

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ping

I'm periodically (every 100 ms) trigger:

```
new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip, 200, new byte[1472], new PingOptions(64, true))
```

After some requests, I stop the sending and `await` all `Task<PingReply>` for `Status` evaluation of `PingReply`. Some Request fail with `IPStatus.TimedOut`, even though I see all responses at Wireshark. Further investigation showed, that those Tasks ran to completion. But their overall time to complete was only around 4 ms. Would have expected at least a time of 200 ms. So requests and responses are at the NIC, but returned PingReply is not correct/timeout is not working... Any Idea?

**Update:**
Problem occurred also when sending once, but hard to reproduce.
But here, the actual code:

```
        _PingOptions = new PingOptions(64, true);
        _PingPayLoad = new byte[1472];
        new Random().NextBytes(_PingPayLoad);

        // Create a Timer Task which cancels the other tasks when elapsed
        var internalCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var testTimeTask = Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000))
            .ContinueWith(_ => internalCTS.Cancel());

        // Create a Task which periodically sends async ping requests (without awaiting the response or timeout)
        List<RequestContainer> taskList = new List<RequestContainer>();
        int request = 0;
        var workingTask = PrecisionTimer.RepeatActionOnIntervalAsync(() =>
        {
            var dummy = new RequestContainer(
                    id: ++request,
                    requestTime: DateTime.Now,
                    requestTask: new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip, 200, _PingPayLoad, _PingOptions));
            dummy.RequestTask.ContinueWith(_ => dummy.EndTime = DateTime.Now);
            taskList.Add(dummy);
        },
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
        internalCTS.Token);
    
        // ... start other tasks to do in parallel

        // Await all tasks
        Task.WhenAll(testTimeTask, ...).Wait();

        // also wait till last ping received
        Task.WhenAll(taskList.Select(t => t.RequestTask).ToArray()).Wait();

        // Do Ping evaluation
        var ipResult = taskList.Select(t => t.RequestTask.Result).ToList();
        var totalPingRequest = ipResult.Count;
        var succeededPingRequests = ipResult
            .Where(i => i.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            .Count();
        double pingRate = (double)succeededPingRequests / totalPingRequest * 100;
```

Info: Interval-Task based on [Precision-Repeat-Action-On-Interval-Async-Method](https://github.com/SunsetQuest/Precision-Repeat-Action-On-Interval-Async-Method) to properly work with small intervals. `RequestContainer` dto inserted for debugging of the current problem. Containing: started and stopped DateTime of the Task, an ID to keep track of the requests and the `Task<PingReply>` Task itself.

Comment: Are you sure you're not overwriting your ping object? What does your loop look like? More code would be helpful - both the code for looping through creating new pings, and the code where you are waiting for all of the Tasks to finish.

Comment: This code is far too convoluted. There's certainly no reason to use `ContinueWith`. Mixing `WhenAll` with `Wait` is *worse* than using `Task.WaitAll`. What are you actually trying to do? You don't need a new `Ping` instance every time. Unless you want to send multiple pings to different destinations, you don't need a List<Task>, you could use `await` to retrieve the response and store it in a List or ConcurrentQueue. Or you could use IAsyncEnumerable and LINQ-to-Async to send pings to the same target *and* calculate the rate. Or use Channels

Comment: If you want to cancel a CTS after 2 seconds the best option is to use [CancellationToken(int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-threading-cancellationtokensource-ctor(system-int32)) to specify a timeout. `PingReply` already contains [RoundTripTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.roundtriptime?view=net-6.0), there's no reason to calculate it again

Comment: I'm sending more requests in a shorter time period as I allow the client to respond. Every 100ms  a new request while timeout can be 200ms. In the realworld example, those times are configurable. Like every 5ms a new request. This will flood my client. It need to withstand a certain testtime. The CTS is just used to stop the timer. The Action inside the timer is just added to gether debug info. usually there would be only the line mentioned in the question. But to make it clear: For me it looks like a bug in the Ping function. Returning after 4ms even though timeout is set to 200

Comment: The reason why I'm currently calculate the roundtripTime on my own: for some requests I get IPStatus.TimedOut prior to the configured timeout. those PingReplys have a RoundTripTime of 0, eventhough I  see times in wireshark of 7ms